# Setting div height on ready and resize

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, height, document-ready

I have a div that I would like to resize based on window height. I have a static height div above it (height=97px) and below it (height = 200px). So far I have the following code:

```
function eventSize(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    eventHeight = windowHeight - 297;
    $('#mainEvent').css('height',eventHeight + 'px');
}
$(document).ready(eventSize);
$(window).resize(eventSize);
```

The code seems to work on resize, but showing up with no height on page load. for reference, the page is located here: [www.fuelogix.com/test/roi.html](http://www.fuelogix.net/test/roi.html). If this can be done with CSS, I am more than open to those options as well.

Comment: just a guess, but try wrapping `$(document).ready(eventSize);` in a setTimeout and see what happens. e.g. `setTimeout(function(){$(document).ready(eventSize);},250);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears you have a other broken javascript on that page. This is most likely preventing it from working. The errors is here

**$(...).cycle is not a function in midMenu.js line 27**

```
 //Background Cycle
$('#backgroundMid').cycle({
```

i was able to express your code a little differently. with no issues.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        eventHeight = windowHeight - 297;
        $('#mainEvent').css('height',eventHeight + 'px');
    }).resize();    
});
```

My other advice would be to calculate the offset instead of using hard coded 297 value.

Comment: It looks like the broken script was blocking this script from firing when the page loaded. Your version of the code works as well. Thank you for your help.